# Is static List<WeakReference> needed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, weak-references

I'm reverse engineering a old windows service that was written in vb.net using ILSpy. I want to rewrite the legacy service in C#. The original service leaks memory.

When I have a look at the source there is the following declaration in the service class:

```
private static List<WeakReference> __ENCList = new List<WeakReference>();
```

This list is used only used in the constructor as follows(imineRun is the service class):

```
List<WeakReference> _ENCList = imineRun.__ENCList;
            Monitor.Enter(_ENCList);
            try
            {
                imineRun.__ENCList.Add(new WeakReference(this));
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_ENCList);
            }
```

Could this list be causing the memory leaks? Is this list needed and what is its purpose?

Comment: And `imineRun.__ENCList` is used nowhere else?

Comment: @sixlettervariables Only used in the constructor

Comment: A Weakreference is an item than can but does not have to be deleted by the GC come collection time. I don't know if the code is an accepted practice or bad coding.

Comment: @NicholasButler I could...I wasn't sure if it was still free and I didn't have it installed. I'm pretty sure it'll give the same results.

Comment: Reflector is no longer free (grumble). A great alternative is dotPeek. But I very much doubt there would be any major difference in the decompiled output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is used nowhere in *your* code, it isn't a necessary part of the service. Now, I took a look around as I've seen this before in IL output and apparently you've stumbled across [Edit-and-Continue code which was left in the service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/03/12/high-memory-due-to-system-weakreference.aspx). Per the blog post it apparently can be a culprit for high memory usage.

> Having modules built in debug mode running on a Production server is never a good idea.  And as it turned out in this case, the debug mode modules combined with the fact that these modules implement the __ENCLIST helper class for Visual Studio’s Edit and Continue feature.

I'll bet it was compiled with full debug support rather than as a release executable.

You can safely ignore this code in your port.

Comment: +1 Will certainly make the OP's life easier if all he has to do is recompile the source in release mode to fix the memory problems :)